# Criar atalho do tipo 'prop' ou 'propfull' no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Gostaria de criar dentro do Visual Studio um atalho do tipo `prop` ou `propfull` para que ele crie automaticamente um trecho de código.

o `prop` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

o `propfull` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar; }
    set { myVar = value; }
}
```

Queria criar um atalho para que ele crie um trecho de código que preciso repetir varias vezes, alguém sabe se isso é possível?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, é possível, isto se chama *snippet*. A documentação do recurso se encontra [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Vá no menu Tools -> Code Snippets Manager e importe o *snippet* que você criou. O arquivo que contém sua definição segue este modelo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<CodeSnippets  
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">  
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">  
        <Header>  
            <Title></Title>  
        </Header>  
        <Snippet>  
            <Code Language="">  
                <![CDATA[]]>  
            </Code>  
        </Snippet>  
    </CodeSnippet>  
</CodeSnippets>
```

Em `CDATA` vai o código que deseja que seja expandido quando digitar a palavra chave escolhida (`<Shortcut>hello</Shortcut>`). É possível criar "variáveis" no gabarito (`$SqlConnString$`):

```
<Declarations>  
    <Literal>  
        <ID>SqlConnString</ID>  
        <ToolTip>Replace with a SQL connection string.</ToolTip>  
        <Default>"SQL connection string"</Default>  
    </Literal>  
    <Object>  
        <ID>SqlConnection</ID>  
        <Type>System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection</Type>  
        <ToolTip>Replace with a connection object in your application.</ToolTip>  
        <Default>dcConnection</Default>  
    </Object>  
</Declarations>
```

Tem um [*plugin* que ajuda](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.SnippetDesigner&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Tem [um da Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.Snippetizer&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Tinha o [SnippetEditor](https://github.com/LiveMirror/SnippetEditor), mas foi abandonado. Também tem outros [comerciais melhores](https://docs.wholetomato.com/default.asp?W476).

Mas não se compara com o [disponível no Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html). É outra vida.

Antes veja se não tem pronto. Existem diversas coleções de *snippets* prontos.

Answer (score 4):

Sim é possível, isso se chama trecho de código ou em inglês ***Snippet***, instale um [Snippet Desinger](https://github.com/mmanela/SnippetDesigner) (totalmente gratuíto) conforme a figura abaixo acessada pelo menu: `Tools -> Extensions and Updates`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e procure o [Snippet Desinger](https://github.com/mmanela/SnippetDesigner):

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após a instalação e reiniciar o seu Visual Studio é simples criar ***Snippet*** para utilizar em seus projetos, no menu `File -> New -> File`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

busque o `Code Snippet`:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

vai abrir um tela com a seguinte caracteristica:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

seguindo a parte superior de configuração:

- Snippet: Nome do Snippet criado
- Language: Escolha a linguagem
- Shortcut: Nome do trecho, apelido
- Na parte cinza o código, que deseja criar a partir desse atalho onde o mesmo pode até conter parâmetros de digitação que são os textos que estão entre `$`.

Nesse caso foi criado um ***Snippet***, para `SqlConnection` como exemplo: digitado `sqlcon` e pressionando <kbd>TAB</kbd> vai ser criado aquele trecho de código e na parte do parâmetro de conexão para digitar, observe:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

com dois <kbd>TAB</kbd> é criado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>Referencias:</sub>

- [Welcome to the Snippet Designer](https://github.com/mmanela/SnippetDesigner)
- [Passo a passo: Criar um trecho de código](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet)